# angular Apollo Bad Request

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, apollo

hello dear developers actually i have a problem
i'm using Appollo in my Ionic/Angular project and i have this simple
mutation in my code

```
CreateUser(email,phone_num,password){    
    return this.apollo
    .mutate<any>({
      mutation: gql`
      mutation create_user($email:String!,$phone_num:String!,$password:String!) {
        create_user(input:{email:$email,phone_num:$phone_num,password:$password}){
          user {
            id
            first_name
            last_name
            phone_num
            email
            biography
            gender
            profile_picture
            created_at
            is_active
          }
    message
    ok
    }
} 
      `,
      variables:{
        email:email,
        phone_num:phone_num,
        password:password
      },
    })
  }
```

when i execute this query in the backend(django) graphical page its working
but in the angular project returns bad request 400
what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

i got it and problem was from types this code is worked

```
CreateUser(email,phone_num,password){    
    return this.apollo
    .mutate<any>({
      mutation: gql`
      mutation create_user($email:String!,$phone_num:String!,$password:String!) {
        create_user(input:{email:$email,phone_num:$phone_num,password:$password}){
          user {
            id
            first_name
            last_name
            phone_num
            email
            biography
            gender
            profile_picture
            created_at
            is_active
          }
    message
    ok
    }
} 
      `,
      variables:{
        email:String(email),
        phone_num:String(phone_num),
        password:String(password)
      },
    })
  }
```